# Printing custom diagnostic information if `testthat` test fails in `R`

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I use a `testthat` unit test to check whether the `data.frame` returned by a function is identical to the one I would expect it to return. If the test fails, `testthat` prints some diagnostic information, for instance:

```
MyFunction(df.orig) is not identical to df.expected. Differences: 
Names: 1 string mismatch
```

However, I would really like to see the actual output of the function, i.e. print the returned `data.frame`. Is there a way to print the output of the tested function (or some other custom diagnostic information) if a `testthat` test fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indirectly, yes! If you look at the arguments for `expect_that`, you'll see the "info" parameter - you can throw an anonymous function or a call in here that'll print the results. So, something like:

```
expect_that(df.orig, is_identical_to(df.expected), info = print(df.orig))
```

The disadvantage of this is that it will /always/ print df.orig or similar information, even if the test passes.

The only other way of doing it (and the only thing that would ensure it *only* triggers if an error occurs) would be to use tryCatch; something like:

```
tryCatch(
    expr = {
        expect_that(df.orig, is_identical_to(df.expected))
    }, 
    error = function(e){
        print(e)
        print(df.orig)
        #And anything else you want to only happen when errors do
    }
)
```

This is a lot clunkier-looking, but has a couple of advantages - it will only print df.orig if the expect_that call produces an error, you can output...well, anything you want, and you can produce different results for errors versus warnings. Fairly gnarly, however.

Answer (score 0):

you could store the result of the expect_that in a temporary variable b, check if it fails inside the it construct and return b

```
b <- expect_that(df.orig, is_identical_to(df.expected))

if (!b$passed){

    #do something
}
```