# "Random unit" testing

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I would like to test a function over a fresh set of numbers every test. The idea is to achieve failure on instances I hadn't anticipated.

```
library(testthat)

hypotenuse_length <- function(a, b){
  sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
}

bad_hypotenuse_length <- function(a, b){
  sqrt(a^2 + b^2) + 1
}

test_that("Hypotenuse is always less than sum of other two sides", {
  a <- abs(rcauchy(1))
  b <- abs(rcauchy(1))
  expect_lte(bad_hypotenuse_length(a, b), a + b)
})
```

The issue is that when I receive a failure, I don't know what values of `a` and `b` triggered the failure.

I can achieve this for a particular operation, by reverse engineering `expect_lte`:

```
my_expect_lte <- function(a, b, actual, expected, label = NULL, expected.label = NULL){
  op <- match.fun("<=")
  lab_act <- testthat:::make_label(actual, label)
  lab_exp <- testthat:::make_label(expected, expected.label)
  stopifnot(is.numeric(actual), length(actual) == 1)
  stopifnot(is.numeric(expected), length(expected) == 1)
  msg <- "not less than"
  diff <- actual - expected
  testthat::expect(op(diff, 0), 
                   sprintf("%s is %s %s. Difference: %.3g. a = %.3g b = %.3g", 
                           lab_act, msg, lab_exp, diff, a, b))
}

set.seed(1)  # not ordinarily present
a <- abs(rcauchy(1))
b <- abs(rcauchy(1))
my_expect_lte(a, b, bad_hypotenuse_length(a, b), a + b)
```

> Error: bad_hypotenuse_length(a, b) is not less than a + b. Difference: 0.143. a = 1.1 b = 2.35

Is there a way to use existing functions to return similar information? That is, returns the same as `expect_...`, but also includes the value of the arguments that were passed. (The solution [Printing custom diagnostic information if `testthat` test fails in `R`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928253/printing-custom-diagnostic-information-if-testthat-test-fails-in-r) either prints the information out regardless of the test outcome or does not fit with existing tests.)

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not have a direct answer to your question, I would suggest using the [quickcheck](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/quickcheck) package, since it provides a framework for randomized testing. It comes with nice tools for inspecting the failure cases (see the `repro` function usage in the [tutorial](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/quickcheck/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md)).